# Cannot select date from datepicker with python3.7 and selenium using the FirefoxWebdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to automate the selection of a predefined date from a datepicker. That datepicker is a pop-up in a bigger pop-up. Cannot work one out.

I've created this function lots of waits because the site is slow

below is the html of the datepicker

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-datepicker-close-button" onclick="CloseDatePicker();"></div><a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._adjustDate('#startDatePicker', +1, 'M');" title="הבא>"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">הבא&gt;</span></a><a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled"
        title="<הקודם"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">&lt;הקודם</span></a>
    <div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">אוגוסט</span> <span class="ui-datepicker-year">2019</span></div>
</div>
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="ראשון">א'</span></th>
            <th><span title="שני">ב'</span></th>
            <th><span title="שלישי">ג'</span></th>
            <th><span title="רביעי">ד'</span></th>
            <th><span title="חמישי">ה'</span></th>
            <th><span title="שישי">ו'</span></th>
            <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="שבת">שבת</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">1</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">2</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">3</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-today" onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">4</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td>
            <td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " onclick="DP_jQuery.datepicker._selectDay('#startDatePicker',7,2019, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">31</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code is below

```
def for_future_date(self):
        driver = self.driver
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#SHOW_CALNDER > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)')))
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
        while start_date == 1:
            confirm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="approve_checkbox"]')
            confirm.click()
        else:  #package starting not today
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SHOW_CALNDER"]')))
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SHOW_CALNDER"]'))).click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
            #WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SHOW_CALNDER"]'))).click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, delay)

            print("opened date picked")
            #WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/strong/div[1]/div[2]/a'))).click()
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-trigger').click()

            selecting_all_dates = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-state-default') # this selects the class of the table which in turn has all the dates
            date_element = driver.find_element_by_name('22')

            date_element.click()
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: I cannot select the 22nd :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the calendar is opened, all you need is the locator below.

```
"//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//a[.='22']"
```

It can be modified further to accept any day so that you can pass in a parameter, `day`, that contains "22" (or whatever the desired date is) and can be reusable.

```
"//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//a[.='" + day + "']"
```

---

Some additional feedback...

1. You can declare a single wait and reuse it.

   ```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
   wait.until(...)
   wait.until(...)
   ```
2. If you are locating an element using only the ID, use `.find_element_by_id('approve_checkbox')` instead of XPath.
3. You don't need to wait for presence and then clickable. An element can't be clicked unless it is present so just wait for clickable.

Comment: I got it to work with |||  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']//a[.='" + day + "']").click()   |||||   Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

'find_element_by_name(foo)' will select element that have `name="foo"`

You want to find elements with "text" matching your search `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("a[@id='ui-state-default'][text() = '22']")`

Comment: tried with elements and with element

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: a[@id='ui-state-default'][text() = '22']
||||||||||||||||||||
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'click'
  File "C:\cell package\package_working - Copy.py", line 174, in for_future_date
    date_element.click()
  File "C:\cell package\package_working - Copy.py", line 200, in <module>
    foo.for_future_date()